# What operators should be used when renaming columns using paste0()?

Tags: r, rename, paste

I am getting an error for `Error: unexpected '}' in "}"` when trying to rename column names using `paste0()`.

For example:

```
df %>% 
    rename(., paste0("text", "index") = old)
```

Am I supposed to be using something other than `=` for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
df %>% 
  rename(., !!paste0("text", "index") := old)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. May I know the significance of ```!!``` and the use of ```:=``` in this context? Or any articles that may point me towards learning about them. I've tried looking for this previously but don't think I am looking for the right articles.

Comment: Sure, may I suggest you visit the question that has been linked above? Also google for "quasiquotation" and "lazy evaluation".

Comment: Absolutely. I'll probably need to spend some time parsing through the thread as most of it seems to be beyond my current capabilities. But it looks very helpful! Thank you.